# Specify which interpreter to use at command line

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, zsh

Ok, so I can write a shell script with `bash`, `sh`, or `zsh` in mind etc. And I can put a hashbang at the top of the file like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

which will tell the kernel which interpreter to use to execute the file.

However, I just realized, I don't know how to tell the machine which interpreter to use at the command line.

e.g., if I write:

```
$ foo bar baz
```

at the command line, how do I know what interpreter is being used to interpret that command? How can I tell the computer to use a particular interpreter?

Hopefully the question is clear.

Comment: mmm, this question is more simply worded - TBH I didn't even know if the command line commands were also interpreted by bash/zsh etc...that was just an educated guess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get your login shell, which is most likely the shell you're currently running, unless you have deliberately chosen a different shell (e.g., by choosing a shell other than your login shell in your terminal emulator's preferences, or by explicitly invoking a shell at login time, such as with `ssh remote-host /path/to/shell`):

```
echo $SHELL
```

To use a different shell:

```
exec /path/to/shell
```

E.g.:

```
exec /bin/bash
```